# Latin justification for the English word tradent

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I was reading the following thread https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tradent.3819293/ - There it is stated that the English word ***tradent***, according to the OED means

> Chiefly in Rabbinic Jewish contexts: a person who hands down or
> transmits (esp. oral) tradition.

I then looked up the origins of ***tradition*** and, found the following:

> tradition (n.)
> late 14c., "statement, belief, or practice handed down from generation
> to generation," especially "belief or practice based on Mosaic law,"
> ... from Latin traditionem (nominative traditio) "a delivering up,
> surrender, a handing down, a giving up"... This is a noun of action
> from past-participle stem of tradere "deliver, hand over," from trans-
> "over" (see trans-) + dare "to give" (from PIE root *do- "to give").
> https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tradition

**Question**

Given that the root of these words is the Latin verb *tradere*, what part of its conjugation in Latin would justifiably lead to the word *tradent*?

---

Note: I have some rudimentary knowledge of Latin but not enough to answer this question for myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The present active participle of *trado* is *tradens* – "handing down" when used adjectively, or "one who hands down" when used as a noun. This leads to English *tradent* in the same way we get nouns like *correspondent* or adjectives like *incipient*.

Comment: +1, but for clarity you could add the Latin verbal forms (correspondens, incipiens) and a comment on -ens/-entis, and how the latter is the preferred root for derived words, not only in English, but in many modern languages, including most from the Romance family